# How do I use google fonts in spfx web parts for SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint, spfx

I'm struggling hard with getting google fonts to render in my spfx component.

In my scss file, I've written the following:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo+2:100,300,400,700,900');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,700,900');
```

and later in my scss I simply address them by

```
font-family: 'Roboto';
```

This works *sometimes*, meaning that the web part sometimes is shown with the right fonts. Sometimes it defaults to standard font. I've looked into other peoples solutions but there are only a few out there and none seems to work for me. Have anyone conquered this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure the CSS applied.

My test result.

```
return (
      <div className={styles.reactSpFx}>

        <div className={styles.container}>
```

.SCSS

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo+2:100,300,400,700,900');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,700,900');

.reactSpFx {
  .container {
    max-width: 700px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 25px 50px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);

    font-family: "Roboto" !important;
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but with no luck. Font still loads occasionally, and in sources it just doesn't show up.